# How to share styles, with props, between emotion/styled styled components, in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I'm using [emotion styled components](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled). I have a `textinput` and an `input`, and I want them to have identical styles. I'm doing this from within a `.tsx` file (that is to say, I'm writing typescript).

I believe it should look something along these lines:

*someView.tsx*

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";


const InputStyling = css`
 width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: ${(props: { invalid?: boolean }) => props.invalid ? red : blue};
`;

export const BaseInput = styled.input<{invalid?: boolean}>`
  ${InputStyling}
`;

export const BaseTextarea = styled.textarea<{invalid?: boolean}>`
  ${InputStyling}
`;
```

This doesn't work, I get the following error when I typecheck:

```
➤ YN0000: src/design_system/TextInput/TextInput.tsx(19,22): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
➤ YN0000:   Overload 1 of 2, '(template: TemplateStringsArray, ...args: CSSInterpolation[]): SerializedStyles', gave the following error.
➤ YN0000:     Argument of type '(props: {    invalid?: boolean;}) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CSSInterpolation'.
➤ YN0000:       Type '(props: { invalid?: boolean | undefined; }) => string' is missing the following properties from type 'CSSInterpolation[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.
➤ YN0000:   Overload 2 of 2, '(...args: CSSInterpolation[]): SerializedStyles', gave the following error.
➤ YN0000:     Argument of type 'TemplateStringsArray' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CSSInterpolation'.
➤ YN0000:       Type 'TemplateStringsArray' is missing the following properties from type 'CSSInterpolation[]': pop, push, reverse, shift, and 6 more.
```

I've browsed many StackOverflow answers, trying slightly different incantations of above. For example, I've tried having an `interface`:

```
interface InputBoi {
  invalid?: boolean
}

export const BaseInput = styled.input<InputBoi>`
  ${resetInputCss}
  ${InputStyling}
`;
```

I got the same error.

I tried using the `styled` factory function style:

```
export const BaseInput = styled('input')<InputBoi>`
  ${resetInputCss}
  ${InputStyling}
`;

export const BaseTextarea = styled('textarea')<{invalid?: boolean}>`
  ${resetInputCss}
  ${InputStyling}
`;
```

Same error for both.

[Emotion's composition style isn't exactly what I want,](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition) this app's structure prefers strongly to avoid any CSS within the `render` function.

[Other StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66023077/2590119) deal with extending other components, but that's not what I want to do, I want to **share css**, not have one component extend another (because one needs to be `input` and the other needs to be `textarea`).

On the emotion repository, I've found [people with similar issues](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1908), but no solution.

A [CSSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667163/2590119) won't work for me, I need to pass props.

**What is the correct way to share styles between two different components when using emotion/styled styled components in a typescript file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a function that returns a `styled` `css` template string, like so:

```
const getInputStyling = ({ invalid } : { invalid: boolean | undefined}) => css`
  width: 100%;
  border-color: ${invalid ? 'red' : 'black'};
`;

export const BaseInput = styled.input<{invalid: boolean | undefined}>`
  ${({invalid}) => getInputStyling({ invalid })}
`;
```